# imgkit snapshot saving issues rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, imgkit

I am using `imgkit` gem in my application to take snapshot of current page 
controller code is

```
kit = IMGKit.new(render_to_string)
t = kit.to_img(:png) 
file_path = '/home/myapp/file.png'
file = kit.to_file(file_path)
```

working fine(image save in myapp/file.png ).

Now my question

- each time this method will overwrite `file.png` that i don't want
- how can i display those saved  images(suppose i give the saving path in images folder in my root app directory)

hope i explain my problem clearly, i am not using S3 for storing instead i am using my local machine

i am using https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit for my reference

Comment: You can append current time to the filename and it will be unique. and not overridden by the new file. if i understand your question correctly that is. and you want to show it in your app? as an index?

Comment: how can i show in my webpage?

Comment: You will need to save the information of each file while saving to a model that way you can use its index to open images of all records on  an index page. other wise I don't think rails can open all files placed in a directory without being explicitly told what the file name is

Comment: i m really not able to appending current time to the path can you show me how it can be done!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file_path = "/home/myapp/#{Time.now}file.png" should do it